# C# Enum type in Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, enums

I'm using Matlab R2010b and I've got an enum under C# :

```
[Flags()]
public enum  MyFormat
{
  value1 = 0,
  value2 = 1,
  value3 = 2,
  value4 = 4,
  value5 = 8
}
```

In a method, I've got an argument which is a format :

```
public void MyMethod(MyFormat format, double number)
{
   ....
}
```

Then I work with Matlab, and I want to use the method MyMethod. In a standard way, here is the code :

```
>>format = MyNamespace.MyFormat.value1;
>>MyNamespace.MyMethod(format, 15);
```

The issue comes when I try to pass a "multiple value" as a MyFormat :

```
>>format = MyNamespace.MyFormat.value1 | MyNamespace.MyFormat.value2;
>>MyNamespace.MyMethod(format, 15);
```

I found a easy solution but it takes a more recent version of Matlab R2011a. Another solution found here was to implement this function in Matlab :

```
function enum = EnumParse(typename, value)   
type = System.Type.GetType(typename);
values = regexp(value, ', ', 'split');

enum = cell(1, length(values));
for i = 1:length(values)
    enum{i} = System.Enum.Parse(type, values{i});
end
end
```

However, the line System.Type.GetType('MyNamespace.MyFormat') returns me a null value, whereas it is not null with a type System.Type.GetType('System.String') for example.

My question is then how to parse multiple values to an enum ?
Thanks !

Comment: doesn't appear that you are parsing multiple values i.e enum.Parse(type, String, Boolean) for example.. '

Comment: What is the easy solution that you found for Matlab R2011a? Please tell, it is interesting

Comment: The easy solution found under R2011a version of Matlab is to use the new function bitor that works directly on bits just as you would do it in C#.. You could find it on mathworks and R2011a documentation

Answer (score 0):

Does MatLab, for it's Enum.Parse take any multiple overloads for example 
type, value, value ...?

Comment: Thank you, however I should have mentionned that I can't work on the C# code, I must only code under Matlab....

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realize that